# Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors when using srvyr and tbl_svysummary in gtsummary

Tags: r, survey, gtsummary

I have been trying to use `tbl_svysummary()` to create a summary table in `gtsummary` for survey data using weights. I am using the `srvyr` package to create the tbl_svy object using `as_survey_design()`. Colleagues have had no issues with this formula and are able to knit outputs to HTML documents with no problems.

Unfortunately every time I try to use `tbl_svysummary()`, I get the error code `Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`. The problem (from examining the traceback and a lot of trial and error) appears to be that the `srvyr`-created tbl_svy objects store the `x$call` component of the dataset differently than `survey` (more on this below). This happens even when using any empty `tbl_svysummary` command (e.g. `data %>% tbl_svysummary()`) but I will use an example with a formatted table for better illustration...

I was able to reproduce the problem using example code and data from the `survey` vs. `srvyr` vignette (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/srvyr/vignettes/srvyr-vs-survey.html) in the "Preparing a survey dataset" section - then trying to plug it into the example `tbl_svysummary` code from the Survey Data section of the `gtsummary` tutorial (http://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/articles/tbl_summary.html#survey-data). I add in the `both` variable to the survey vs. srvyr code for the sake of easily plugging into the gtsummary tutorial code.

Without further ado...
Packages:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(survey)
library(srvyr)
library(gtsummary)
```

The following code:

```
strat_design_survey <- svydesign(~1, strata = ~stype, fpc = ~fpc,
                                 variables = ~stype + api99 + api00 + api.stu + both,
                                 weight = ~pw, data = apistrat)

strat_design_srvyr %>%
  tbl_svysummary(
    # stratify summary statistics by the "both" column
    by = both, 
    # summarize a subset of the columns
    include = c(api00, api99, both),
    # adding labels to table
    label = list(api00 ~ "API in 2000",
                 api99 ~ "API in 1999")
  ) %>%
  add_p() %>%   # comparing values by "both" column
  add_overall() %>%
  # adding spanning header
  modify_spanning_header(c("stat_1", "stat_2") ~ "**Met Both Targets**")
```

Produces a perfect-looking `gtsummary output`, which you can see here:
[Ideal tbl_svysummary output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKmUT.png).

While this code:

```
strat_design_srvyr <- apistrat %>%
  as_survey_design(1, strata = stype, fpc = fpc, weight = pw,
                variables = c(stype, both, starts_with("api"))) 

strat_design_srvyr %>%
  tbl_svysummary(
    # stratify summary statistics by the "both" column
    by = both, 
    # summarize a subset of the columns
    include = c(api00, api99, both),
    # adding labels to table
    label = list(api00 ~ "API in 2000",
                 api99 ~ "API in 1999")
  ) %>%
  add_p() %>%   # comparing values by "both" column
  add_overall() %>%
  # adding spanning header
  modify_spanning_header(c("stat_1", "stat_2") ~ "**Met Both Targets**")
```

Produces this error: `Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`

Looking through the traceback, the error appears to happen when `tbl_svysummary()` attempts to execute this function: `all.vars(x$call$id)`. Simply typing the following into the console provides the same error: `strat_design_srvyr$call$id`, `strat_design_srvyr$call$weights`, etc. Of course the equivalent for the tbl_svy generated by `svydesign()` does not encounter the same issue (i.e. `strat_design_survey$call$weight`). Something appears to be amiss with how `srvyr` produces the tbl_svy, which is in turn messing up the subsetting required for `tbl_svysummary()`.

And before anyone comments, "why don't you just use `svydesign()`?" I am (a) hoping to sort out using `srvyr` and `as_survey_design()` instead, since the latter seems to work for my colleagues, and (b) having trouble with getting a `svydesign()`-generated tbl_svy to work on my actual data and code (which I cannot share due to size and privacy issues), likely partly to due to the fact that it is part of a fairly intricate Rmd code which I would prefer not to need to alter.

Finally, I have already tried updating, uninstalling, and reinstalling all related packages, restarting the R session, ending the session and restarting RStudio entirely, and restarting my computer.

Comment: Hi Chris, The tbl_svysummary function was written for use with the survey package. If you'd like to request support for survey objects created with the srvyr package, I suggest you make the feature request on the gtsummary GitHub page.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Will make the request.

Comment: For anyone interested - the feature request and subsequent upgrade is here: https://github.com/ddsjoberg/gtsummary/issues/886

Thanks again Daniel and Joseph!